# prevent .gitignore from showing ignored files

Tags: html, css, git

I have a couple of files in my project such as:

```
project/*.css
project/tmp
```

I have put them in the .gitignore file and they are not being tracked by default, but when I go to the terminal and run `git status` they keep showing on the untracked files.

Is there a way for git to not even mention these files?

I want this so I can just run `git add project` to add all files from the `project` folder without even considering these files I need it to really ignore.

Comment: Double-check your `.gitignore` settings. `git status` should normally not show those files.

Comment: Please post your `.gitignore` file and the output of `git status`.

Comment: My `.gitignore`` file has what I show in the question besides the commented default stuff

Comment: Can you please post the output of `git status`?

Comment: I just outputs my untracked files

Answer (score 0):

If the `css` files are shown in the untracked section of a git status, that means they are not ignored, meaning none of the `.gitignore` (the one in the same folder, or in one of the parent folders) has a rule for those files.

You can double-check that with a `git check-ignore -v -- yourFile.css`
(Thanks to the work of  Adam Spiers that he mentioned in [GitMinutes episode 32](http://episodes.gitminutes.com/2015/03/gitminutes-32-adam-spiers-on-git-deps.html))

Answer (score 0):

In general your .gitignore should be on the root, and here is an example files structure:

```
project/
    css/
        ...
    js/ 
        ...
    index.html
    .git/
    .gitignore
```

now if you want to ignore the css folder in on git, you should have this on your .gitignore file:

```
 css/
 anotherIgnoredFile.txt
```

and if you still see the files inside css folder on git status, so it was probably added in the past or something, so you should delete them from git with this terminal command:

```
git rm -r css
```

I'm not sure about the -r or -R or nothing but this helped me in the past with the same situation.